# No. of nodes created greater than the no. of rows actually present in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

While creating nodes, I am executing the below query:

```
load csv with headers from "file:C:/Users/abc/Documents/Neo4j/airports.csv" as airports 
create (a1:Airport {label: airports.label, city: airports.city, state: airports.state});
```

My csv file is as follows:

```
label   city       state
DTW   Detroit     Michigan
ATL   Atlanta     Georgia
PIT   Pittsburgh  Pennsylvannia
BOS   Boston      Massachussetts
```

When executed, it shows :

```
"Added 51 labels, created 51 nodes"
instead of 
"Added 4 labels, created 4 nodes, set 12 properties"
```

Anyone can tell me why and how it is creating 51 labels instead of 4 labels?

Comment: What is the correct output, 51 or 4 nodes, you seem to show both here

Comment: 4 nodes should be the output.

Comment: how many rows does your csv contains ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen .. I have already specified the details in my query.

Comment: Yes but your question contains 2 different outputs : One for 51 labels and one for 4 labels, which are the output of 2 different queries, not one

Comment: When executed, it shows(Actual output coming) :

"Added 51 labels, created 51 nodes"

INSTEAD OF the below OUTPUT (Below is the expected output): 

"Added 4 labels, created 4 nodes, set 12 properties"